# Windows 10 Bash and Google Chrome with filepath parameter

Tags: linux, windows, bash, powershell, google-chrome

I am attempting to use Windows 10 Bash as an alternative to PowerShell, as my requirements towards neither of them are high. As of now I am satisfied with quickly navigating the system and using tools such as `grep`.

To my question:

At this moment I attempt to open PDF files (or any files for that matter) using the Kali Linux Client of Windows 10. This means I run a Kali Linux Bash in Windows 10 and try opening a `.pdf` file located at `C:\Folder\Subfolder\MyFile.pdf`, similar to the way I am used to on my Ubuntu machine. The command does not appear to be working however. The command I use:

```
root@PC01:/mtn/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe /mnt/c/Folder/Subfolder/MyFile.pdf
```

Chrome will then open, however skips the file, *i.e.* it will open the default window. The path of the `.pdf` does autocomplete, indicating it is correct. For comparison: I can trigger Chrome along with the `.pdf` file I intend to open passed as parameter with this command:

```
PS C:\> & '.\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe' 'C:\Folder\Subfolder\Manual.pdf'
```

This PowerShell command works fine. It will open Chrome and Chrome in turn will open the filepath passed as parameter.

Is the reason this is not working in the Win10 Kali Linux Bash a mistake on my part? Or does Chrome run into trouble trying to interpret the path passed as parameter in the Kali Linux VM (I assume it is a VM, correct me if this is wrong, please), so that it cannot find the specified location?

My attempt to stringify the parameters was not met with success. Also I was able to find information on how to start Windows programs from the Linux bash, however not how to pass a filepath parameter properly, so apologies in advance if I happened to miss something.

Thank you, looking forward to the replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you start Chrome through the bash shell, the program itself will not know how to handle the bash-style file path. As it is a Windows based program it will however know how to handle the DOS-style path.
So you can simply use:

`/mtn/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe 'C:\Folder\Subfolder\Manual.pdf'`

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. This does make sense, since if the file was started in some sort of virtual machine, then I would not have been able to run an `.exe` in the first place.